# DNS connections to my ISP during TOR?

Tags: dns, privacy, tor, little-snitch

With Little Snitch on my mac, I noticed that during TOR/TorButton use (latest version), little snitch says there's still an occasional DNS connection to my ISP.  What's the purpose of this, is it a breach of my anonymity?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way we can know without seeing the packet traces. There are two possibilities:

1. You aren't using `tor` through a proxy that forwards DNS. So all your DNS requests are bypassing `tor`.
2. Other things going on are doing DNS requests that aren't being anonymized (and probably shouldn't be). Things like time synchronization, for example.